# Check if NSMutableArray contains text from textfield

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview, textfield

I want to check if the text inserted in a textfield is also in my NSMutableArray.
So let's say my NSMutableArray has these objects: "Hey, Hello, No, Yes".
Then when a user enters the text: "Hello" i want there to appear a UIAlertView. I now have the following:

```
for (int slt = 0; slt < [zouten count]; slt++) {
        if (zout.text = [zouten objectAtIndex:slt]) {

            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Goedzo!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Je hebt een zout gevonden"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        }
    }

    [alert show];
```

But somehow the message appears with every word. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you compare like this:

```
if (zout.text = [zouten objectAtIndex:slt])
```

you are actually assigning instead of comparing so it will be TRUE always.Therefore instead of using =, you should compare like this:

```
if ([zout.text isEqualToString:[zouten objectAtIndex:slt]])
```

Your code should be:

```
for (int slt = 0; slt < [zouten count]; slt++) {
        if ([zout.text isEqualToString:[zouten objectAtIndex:slt]]) {
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Goedzo!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Je hebt een zout gevonden"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [alert show];
           [alert release];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isEqualToString` method to compare strings.

```
if([zout.text isEqualToString:[zouten objectAtIndex:slt]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could make your code more concise by converting to a set and checking for the entry, e.g.

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray: zouten];
if([set containsObject:zout.text]) {
   ...
}
```